# Differences between generic methods in java

Tags: java, oop, generics, methods, generic-programming

Suppose I have this interface:

```
public interface Lookup<T> {
     public T find(String name);
}
```

Are there differences between the following methods?

1)

```
public void process(String name, Lookup<?> table) {
    System.out.println(table.find(name));
}
```

2)

```
public <S,T extends Lookup<S>> void process(String name, T table) {
    System.out.println(table.find(name));
}
```

In the first method I am using '?' so I can use any type inside Lookup, and in the second I use T and S so S so I also can use any type inside T witch is Lookup.

Comment: After type erasure they will both look like the first one.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is not found within the `process()` method, it's found in the invoker. When you specify `Lookup<?>` you give up any opportunity for compile-time type checking, whereas if you use the second method your `table` has to match `T extends Lookup<S>`. You at least have some hope of the compiler catching problems.

Comment: Since there is no restriction on `S`, there is no kind of error, a compiler could catch here. Any `Lookup` is acceptable, hence, it’s no difference to `Lookup<?>`…

Comment: @Holger almost. If I invoke it with `<Foo, FooLookup>process("Baz", myBarLookup)` (where `FooLookup extends Lookup<Foo>` and `myBarLookup` is an instance of `BarLookup extends Lookup<Bar>` then the compiler can catch it. Hence the "at least ... some hope" line.

Comment: Sure, but why should anyone provide these explicit `<Foo, FooLookup>` type arguments just to make the compiler reject the call, whereas passing `myBarLookup` without type arguments to the method is not only accepted, but will actually *work* without problems, as the method itself does not depends on neither, `Foo` nor `Bar`? The point here is not that we can’t catch all errors, but that there *is* no error to catch. The methods work will all subtypes of `Lookup` and the opportunity to make the compiler reject things which the method actually can handle, is no win.

Comment: @Holger the method is contrived (trivial `println`), the example of usage is contrived, and the usage scenario is notional. The point is that there _is_ a difference. Whether it is useful is another question. And I _almost_ completely agree with you that the potential utility of the second declaration is very slim.

Comment: As long as the implementation is simple enough to actually work with a `Lookup<?>` (or generally, a wildcard type), there is no reason to introduce named type variables for it. The caller can’t do anything wrong regarding the actual type then. If the implementation does not work with a wildcard type, however, there is no question which declaration to use…

Comment: @Holger Ah, at last we agree :-) Well stated.

Answer (score 0):

1. `table.find` will return `T`, which if it's not String need to be converted to a String:

   System.out.println(table.find(name).toString());
2. doesn't much sense to me,